# Are there any solutions to $x^2 \equiv 88 \mod 22801763489$

Tags: number-theory

Are there any solutions to $x^2 \equiv 88\mod 22801763489$?

$22801763489$ is a prime number.

does this question have anything to do with quadratic residues?

Comment: If our prime is $p$, we want $(88/p)$, so we want $(2/p)(11/p)$. The first is $1$. For the second, use Quadratic Reciprocity.

Comment: @AndréNicolas but the prime is really big. I don't think the point of the question is to use reciprocity though.

Comment: Could be. The prime is big but finding its remainder on division by $11$ is not particularly difficult.

Comment: I'm just wondering if there is another way to solve without calculating using Legendre symbols. What if p is even much bigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a Legendre symbol calculation. Call our prime $p$. Then
$$(88/p)=(22/p)=(2/p)(11/p).$$
Looking at the last three digits we see that $p\equiv 1\pmod{8}$, so $(2/p)=1$.

By Quadratic Reciprocity, $(11/p)=(p/11)$. But $p\equiv -1\pmod{11}$, so since $11\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ we have $(-1/11)=-1$. Thus $(22/p)=-1$, and our congruence has no solution.

Comment: No, you've go this backwards. Evaluating $(p/11)$ means testing whether $p$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod{11}$. Since $p\equiv-1\pmod{11}$, this is the same as testing whether $-1$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod{11}$, and that's not the case because $11\equiv-1\pmod4$. Just try testing a similar case with another $p\equiv1\pmod4$ and $p\equiv-1\pmod{11}$ such as $p=109$. You can run out all the possibilities for such a small prime and show that $(11/109)=-1$.

Comment: @user5713492: Thanks, I forgot I was working with $11$, which is congruent to $3$ modulo $4$.